# Error while installing Perl package Term::ReadKey in Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, svn, perl

I'm trying to use git via cygwin

Well, I used this command to clone the svn content to a local git repository:

```
git svn clone svn://path/to/my/project --username myuser
```

Git was returning:

```
Authentication realm: <svn://path/to/my/project>
Password for 'myuser': Can't locate Term/ReadKey.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl
/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-   
threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 .) at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/Git.pm line 565.
```

Google said I should use the perl shell and that's what I did:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

After the shell initiation I should install the Perl Term ReadKey package:

```
install Term::ReadKey
```

And now my problem appeared, the installation of the Term::ReadKey package failed with this error message:

```
gcc -c   -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector 
-DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.32\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.32\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-  
cygwin-threads/CORE"   ReadKey.c
ReadKey.xs:3:20: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
#include "EXTERN.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:327: recipe for target 'ReadKey.o' failed
make: *** [ReadKey.o] Error 1
JSTOWE/TermReadKey-2.32.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
JSTOWE/TermReadKey-2.32.tar.gz               : make NO
```

Google found this question, which is related to my problem: [gcc not finding header file though its path has been included with -I](https://superuser.com/questions/647400/gcc-not-finding-header-file-though-its-path-has-been-included-with-i)
But the right marked answer is not helping.
I've installed all crypt libs in cygwin, cygwin-GCC and Make are installed from the beginning and it is still not working.

Would be cool if anyone could help me, thanks.

Edit:

```
find / -iname "*EXTERN.h*"
```

returns

```
/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE/EXTERN.h
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE/EXTERN.h
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the solution was..... install TermReadKey Cygwin package from cygwin installer.
Such an easy solution :)

Thanks to atrigent for this idea!